# How to initialize a uint16[] array?

Tags: solidity, arrays

I have a hard time creating a uint16[] array in an elegant way.

I try this:

```
function init() public {
uint16[] memory x = [uint16(1), uint16(1)];
test(x)
}
```

This raises `TypeError: Type uint16[2] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint16[]`

I want to use this initialized array in a

```
function test(uint16[] input){}
```

function

I can of course create a `uint16[]` array and the push values in it, but this is not an elegant way of initializing it. How do I correctly initialize these values?

Comment: In which scope is the line `uint16[] memory = [uint16(1), uint16(1)];`?

Comment: It is in a public function. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current version of Solidity (v.0.4.21), fixed size memory arrays cannot be assigned to dynamically-sized memory arrays.

Check out the documentation on `Array Literals / Inline Arrays` in the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#array-literals-inline-arrays).

The following code will not work:

```
// This will not compile.

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract C {
    function f() public {
        // The next line creates a type error because uint[3] memory
        // cannot be converted to uint[] memory.
        uint[] x = [uint(1), 3, 4];
    }
}
```

The documentation says:

> It is planned to remove this restriction in the future but currently
>   creates some complications because of how arrays are passed in the
>   ABI.